# What is the use of initializationStatus -> in MobileAds.initialize()?

Tags: java, android, admob

So I know that MobileAds.initialize() is used to reduce latency on the session's first ad request. But the structure as I have seen is MobileAds.initialize(context,app_id), so what is the use of "initializationStatus -> " then ? I have also seen that someone said that "MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
});" is not working anymore, is that true? Is it OK if I use it?

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Each GMA SDK update may change some initialization methods.

> "is not working anymore, is that true?"

It depends on which version you use. At latest version it will work.

Latest GMA SDK v21.1.0 has only these methods for initialization.

```java
public static void initialize(@NonNull Context context) 

public static void initialize(@NonNull Context context,
 @NonNull OnInitializationCompleteListener listener)
```

Also, `MobileAds.initialize(context, app_id)` was removed from the library, not available anymore in GMA SDK.

Comment: So if I am using "MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> { });", how can I know that it is working? Is there any method to know that it is working? Thanks

Comment: Even if you don't init MobileAds, GMA SDK will init it at first request.